# 'Cannot GET /' in NodeJS Express-Handlebars, What to do?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

This is the code

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

var hbsHelpers = exphbs.create({
    helpers: require("./helpers/handlebars.js").helpers,
    defaultLayout: '',
    extname: '.hbs'
});

const app = express();
app.engine('hbs', hbsHelpers.engine);
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.render('index.hbs');
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Everything looks perfect and no errors in terminal/logcat.

But getting output 'Cannot GET /'.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message occurs `Cannot GET /` if you don't **specify** which page it is that you're trying to **get**. `http://localhost:3000/` in this case.

I was able to fire up your code but I had to disable some `import`,`export` and `function` that I cannot access.

```
// const firebase = require("firebase-admin");
const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const port = 3000;

// var hbsHelpers = exphbs.create({
//   helpers: require("./helpers/handlebars.js").helpers,
//   defaultLayout: "",
//   extname: ".hbs",
// });

const app = express();
app.engine("hbs", exphbs.engine());
app.set("views", "./views");
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index.hbs");
});

// exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is  listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

---

Folder & File structure:

[image]

---

Output:
[image]